# reference in theorem environment

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I am using `theorem` environment and want to put reference near the lemma, however, instead of `[18]` I am getting `(18)`, how I can fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}%
\AtEndEnvironment{theorem}{\null\hfill\qedsymbol}%
\begin{document}
    \begin{lemma}[18]
        This is an important theorem.
    \end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! I'd like to remark that `\null\hfill\qedsymbol` is not the right way for adding a tombstone at the end of a theorem statement.

Answer (score 3):

The default for `\thmhead`'s `plain` style is to set its argument inside `(`parentheses`)`. Below is an updated version of `\thmhead` that sets the note using `[`brackets`]` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}%

\renewcommand{\thmhead}[3]{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ [#3]}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}[18]
This is an important theorem.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Note that this will hold for all theorem's defined. If you want a different for other theorems, then you need to set a specific style for each.